# Adding parameters to request with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I recently followed the [CodeSchool course to learn iOS](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-ios) and they recommend using AFNetworking to interact with the server.

I am trying to get a JSON from my server, but I need to pass some parameters to the urls. I do not wish to add these parameters to the URL since they contain user passwords.

For a simple URL request I have the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myserver.com/usersignin"];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
       JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
               success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
               } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                        NSLog(@"NSError: %@",error.localizedDescription);             
               }];

[operation start];
```

I have checked the documentation of [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy) but didn't get anything useful from there.

How should I pass a username and password to this request to be read in the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an `AFHTTPClient`:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myserver.com/"];
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"usersignin" parameters:@{"key":@"value"}];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
   JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
           success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",JSON);
           } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                    NSLog(@"NSError: %@",error.localizedDescription);             
           }];

[operation start];
```

Ideally, you'd subclass `AFHTTPClient` and use its `postPath:parameters:success:failure:` method, instead of creating an operation manually and starting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can set POST parameters on an NSURLRequest this way:

```
NSString *username = @"theusername";
NSString *password = @"thepassword";

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *usernameEncoded = [username stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *passwordEncoded = [password stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:[@"username=%@&password=%@", usernameEncoded, passwordEncoded];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

In other words, you create a query string the same way as if you were passing the parameters in the URL, but set the method to `POST` and put the string in the HTTP body instead of after the `?` in the URL.

Comment: Yes, behind the scene of HTTPClient **requestWithMethod:path:parameters:**